# Display accurate timing

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, lateral-join

I have the following query

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN CS.StartTime > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN 'STARTING LATER'
        WHEN x.timing <  30 THEN 'A LITTLE LATE' 
        WHEN x.timing >= 30 THEN 'VERY LATE'
        ELSE 'Unknown Status'
    END as RefreshStartStatus,
    CASE WHEN CS.StartTime <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN CONCAT(x.timing ', min(s) late') END as info
FROM #CSTempTable CS
LEFT OUTER JOIN #SubscriptionAggTempTable SA ON SA.SubscriptionID = CS.SubscriptionID
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CS.StartTime, SA.TodayFirstRunTime))) as x(timing)
```

Example Result:

```
RefreshStartStatus  info
A LITTLE LATE       0 min(s) late
STARTING LATER      NULL
A LITTLE LATE       9 min(s) late
A LITTLE LATE       0 min(s) late
STARTING LATER      NULL
A LITTLE LATE       0 min(s) late
VERY LATE           46 min(s) late
Unknown Status      min(s) late
A LITTLE LATE       0 min(s) late
```

This is good, but the 0's are a little misleading. it maybe a millisecond difference that is making the refresh a little late, so how can I make this display accurate time instead?

e.g.

```
A LITTLE LATE       2 sec(s) late
A LITTLE LATE       1 min(s) late
```

or if that is complicated to do, then

```
A LITTLE LATE       0.03 min(s) late
A LITTLE LATE       1 min(s) late
```

Note: 2 seconds equates to 0.0333 mins

Comment: Have you considered use a `datetime2(0)` instead of a `datetime`? Or, if you only want it accurate to a minute, then a `smalldatetime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this for deference less than 60 second and deference greater than 60 second

```
 SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN CS.StartTime > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN 'STARTING LATER'
    WHEN x.timing <  1800*1000 THEN 'A LITTLE LATE' 
    WHEN x.timing >= 1800*1000 THEN 'VERY LATE'
    ELSE 'Unknown Status'
END as RefreshStartStatus,
CASE WHEN CS.StartTime <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN 
    CASE WHEN x.timing < 1000 THEN
        CONCAT(x.timing ,', millisecond(s) late')
    WHEN x.timing < 60000 THEN
        CONCAT(x.timing/1000 ,', Second(s) late')
    ELSE
        CONCAT(x.timing/60000 ,', min(s) late')
    END
ELSE
CASE WHEN ABS(x.timing) < 1000 THEN
        CONCAT(ABS(x.timing) ,', millisecond(s) until it starts')
    WHEN ABS(x.timing) < 60000 THEN
        CONCAT(ABS(x.timing)/1000 ,', Second(s) until it starts')
    ELSE
        CONCAT(ABS(x.timing)/60000 ,', min(s) until it starts')
    END
END as info
FROM #CSTempTable CS
LEFT OUTER JOIN #SubscriptionAggTempTable SA ON SA.SubscriptionID = CS.SubscriptionID
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, CS.StartTime, SA.TodayFirstRunTime))) as x(timing)
```

I create two temp table and test the result:

```
CREATE TABLE #CSTempTable
(
StartTime dateTime,
SubscriptionID int
)
CREATE TABLE #SubscriptionAggTempTable
(
SubscriptionID int,
TodayFirstRunTime datetime
)
```

And insert two rows in tables

```
 INSERT INTO #CSTempTable
VALUES (DATEADD(SECOND,-10,GETDATE()),1)

INSERT INTO #CSTempTable
VALUES (DATEADD(SECOND,10,GETDATE()),1)

INSERT INTO #CSTempTable
VALUES (DATEADD(MILLISECOND,-150,GETDATE()),1)

INSERT INTO #CSTempTable
VALUES (DATEADD(SECOND,-170,GETDATE()),1)

INSERT INTO #SubscriptionAggTempTable
VALUES (1,GETDATE())
```

After run then query the result is :

[image: Result]

Comment: oh this is awesome! what if its millisecond? for example, 0.4 seconds

Comment: I changed the result for millisecond too

Comment: excellent! one more thing, for "Starting Later" it displays NULL in Info, which is expected...but could we instead show how many min(s)/sec(s)/milliseconds until it starts? Ive considered another VALUES() statement like this: `CROSS APPLY (VALUES (DATEDIFF(SECOND, CS.StartTime, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))) as x2(timing2)` but not sure if thats the right approach

Comment: I changed the result for start later too

Comment: Thank you! This is wonderful. There is the Unknown Status, its displaying "min(s) until it starts" in the info column. I want to display NULL or just leave it empty if the status is Unknown. Ive tried including this statement: `AND RefreshStartStatus != 'Unknown Status'`, however, im getting the following error: `Invalid column name RefreshStartStatus`

Answer (score 1):

Then compute the difference in seconds, then do the math:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN CS.StartTime > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN 'STARTING LATER'
        WHEN x.timing <  30 * 60 THEN 'A LITTLE LATE' 
        WHEN x.timing >= 30 * 60 THEN 'VERY LATE'
        ELSE 'Unknown Status'
    END as RefreshStartStatus,
    CASE WHEN CS.StartTime <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN CONCAT(x.timing / 60.0,  ' min(s) late') END as info
FROM #CSTempTable CS
LEFT OUTER JOIN #SubscriptionAggTempTable SA ON SA.SubscriptionID = CS.SubscriptionID
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (DATEDIFF(SECOND, CS.StartTime, SA.TodayFirstRunTime))) as x(timing)
```

You might want to format, round or truncate the result of the division in case it does not give a precise result, like:

```
CONCAT(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), x.timing / 60.0),  ' min(s) late')
```

Or if you want to show decimal digits only if they are significant, use `FORMAT()`:

```
CONCAT(FORMAT(x.timing / 60.0, '0.##'),  ' min(s) late')
```

Comment: @Cataster: then use `FORMAT()`: see my update.

Comment: awesome this is great!! btw, can we do something about the Unknown Status? instead of showing "min(s) late", display NULL or `???`

Comment: @Cataster: something like: `CASE WHEN CS.StartTime <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND x.timing IS NOT NULL THEN ...`